# C# - Will closing a JsonTextWriter close the underlying StreamWriter

Tags: c#, json

Will the JsonTextWriter close the underlying stream when closed? I am getting a Code Analysis warning that the StreamWriter 'sw' may be disposed of more than once in this scenario. However in the constructor of the StreamWriter I specify true for the 'leaveOpen' argument that I believed would keep the strema open and have to be manually closed using sw.Close().

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false), 1024, true);
JsonTextWriter jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
jtw.Close();
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boolean property `JsonTextWriter.CloseOutput` controls the behavior on this. This is set to `true` by default as per the current [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs).

You may prevent closing the underlying writer in your sample by setting it to false:

```
jtw.CloseOutput = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the JsonSoft documentation, if you set the CloseOutput property of the JsonWriter to true, then it will also close the StreamWriter.  I'd set that property and remove sw.Close in order to ensure there is no ambiguity